# SignalR limit connection count

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

I'm using SingalR OWIN project and looking to `limit the number of connected clients` at one time.

I have the following code which tracks the number of connections:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
if (ConnectionManager.IsAllowed) // checks number of connected clients < 3
{
    ConnectionManager.connectedClients++;
    _log.Debug("Connected = " + ConnectionManager.connectedClients);
    return base.OnConnected();
}
else
{
    return null; // I thought this would reject the incoming connection 
                  // but it does not.
}
}
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to reject the incoming new connection? I can't find any examples online.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in SignalR, I'll gladly remove this if someone else who is has a built in way, but I'd just make my function indicate somehow that the connection was refused. For instance, you could return a bool and check client-side whether it was allowed or not, then act accordingly. If you need something to be returned if it is connected, return a complex type that encompasses a bool `IsSuccess` and a property of whatever type you want to return, then again check client-side whether `IsSuccess` is true. It's not like SignalR actively refusing a connection would do anything more than that, anyway. Unless of course you're looking to, for instance, throw a 404 if a client connects after the limit has been reached.

It wouldn't surprise me if there were some built-in way through web.config to set a connection limit, but that's how I would do it. Then you also have a bit more control, too. For instance, if you wanted, you could tell the client how many people are connected. Just as an example.

**Edit:**

I originally didn't realize you were in the `OnConnected` method. Again, it's quite conceivable that there's a better option, for instance I don't know what happens if you throw an exception in that method. But in most real-world implementations of SignalR that I've seen, there's an "entry method" of sorts that you write yourself. For instance, the client might call and request, as is the typical example, to join a particular chat room. I'd put my check in there, personally. Then you can simply return a `bool` for whether they are allowed to enter.

Even if you don't already have one of those, you could always add something for `BeginListening` and do your check there.

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I return bool knowing when OnConnected() returns Task type?

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have implemented the above and taken away the responsibility of authorisation from the onConnected event.